# How to automatically execute deployed war file in Jboss?

Tags: java, jsf-2, deployment, jboss

I am running jsf application on Jboss. Every time I start JBoss, the war file is successfully deployed, but I have to manually open the browser and enter the URL to start the application. The problem is that this app should start automatically when the server is restarted. I have a shell script that starts JBoss, but the app is started only when I open the browser and enter the url.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with adding @Singleton and @Startup annotations to my starting managed bean class.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any servlet in your war file then load that servlet on application startup. And start the execution in init method of that servlet.

Comment: In the web.xml file i have: 
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
My app uses managed beans and no servlets.